# Oracle SQL DATE datatype returns latest date as 31/12/99 despite younger records

Tags: sql, oracle, date

This is hurting me.
Oracle RDMS using SQL Devloper v. 4
I have records in the table

```
EMP|DATE_STARTED
JOE|11/08/06
BOB|11/08/14
MAY|31/12/99
```

DATE_STARTED is DATE datatype.

My query below returns 31/12/99 as the latest date, but the table has later records (2006 and 2014).

```
select max(DATE_STARTED) from EMPLOYEE;
```

Why doesn't it return 11/08/14?

Comment: Are you certain that `DATE_STARTED` is a date column, and not a `varchar`, which would explain why a string beginning with `31` is viewed as "greater" than strings beginning with `11` ?

Comment: i am not sure of the setting, but i would investigate in the century-setting? maybe on insert oracle interpreted 99 as 2099?

Comment: Describe the table and show us that `date_started` is `date` type.

Comment: Configure your SQL client to show you the **complete** date value, not just a two-digit year. Ideally a format where you can distinguish between month, year and day

Comment: Solved thanks all. 

Solution:
1. in SQL Developer go to Tools\Preferences\Database\NLS Parameters\Date
2. update DD/MON/RR hh24:mi:ss to DD/MON/RR*RR* hh24:mi:ss

and it delivers the expected results! @a_horse_with_no_name was on the same track I was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make you understand why are you getting 31/12/99 as the latest date, see the demo .

Your original query:

```
with sample_table (EMP,DATE_STARTED) as (
                      select 'JOE', '11/08/06' from dual
                     union all
                      select 'BOB', '11/08/14' from dual
                      union all
                      select 'MAY', '12/08/99' from dual

                     )
select max(DATE_STARTED)  
  from  sample_table
```

Output

```
12/08/99
```

I add `to_date` to and display the dates once again.

```
with sample_table (EMP,DATE_STARTED) as (
                      select 'JOE',to_date('11/08/06','dd-mm-yy')from dual
                     union all
                      select 'BOB', to_date('11/08/14','dd-mm-yy') from dual
                      union all
                     select 'MAY', to_date('12/08/99','dd-mm-yy') from dual

                     )
select DATE_STARTED-- max(DATE_STARTED)  
  from  sample_table
```

Output:

```
11-08-2006
11-08-2014
12-08-2099
```

Now from the output of the above query you can see that the result which oracle returned is pretty correct. The max date from the above result set is `12-08-99`.
So the inference from the above is when you don't specify the year as `yyyy` ,Oracle does implicit conversion and set the yy value depending on its system parameters.

To fix your issue you need something like below.

```
with sample_table (EMP,DATE_STARTED) as (
                      select 'JOE',to_date('11/08/2006','dd-mm-yy')from dual
                     union all
                      select 'BOB', to_date('11/08/2014','dd-mm-yy') from dual
                      union all
                     select 'MAY', to_date('12/08/1999','dd-mm-yy') from dual

                     )
select max(DATE_STARTED)  
 from  sample_table
```

Output:

```
11-08-2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks all.

Solution:

1. in SQL Developer go to Tools\Preferences\Database\NLS Parameters\Date
2. update DD/MON/RR hh24:mi:ss to DD/MON/RR*RR* hh24:mi:ss

and it delivers the expected results!